# Lightning Event firing but doing nothing

Tags: lightning-aura-components

For the context, my idea is the same as in the Lightning Component Dev's Guide at step 6 for the standalone app : Make the App Interactive With Events

The only difference is I don't render the form on my page at the moment the event is triggered from the list.

As for the code, the event is fired from a component A as seen here

```
update: function(component, event) {   
    var elem = event.getSource().getElement();
    var selected = elem.textContent;
    var item= component.get("v.item");
    item.Status__c = selected;
    var updateEvent = $A.get("e.c:updateItem");
    updateEvent.setParams({ "item": item}).fire();
}
```

The event

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
  <aura:attribute name="item" type="Item__c"/>
</aura:event>
```

The line in my form to receive the event

```
    <aura:handler event="c:updateItem" action="{!c.updateEvent}" />
```

I added the updateItem in my form, as it is an application level event, it should be received and treated, although it doesn't trigger my c.updateEvent. Maybe because it isn't rendered ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welp, I just tried by rendering my form .. and it works.

So you can't use an application level event for a component not rendered !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my comment above.

Have a nice day